# How are discrete time systems (with negative indices) represented in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, discrete-mathematics

So I'm trying to represent discrete time systems in numpy, which means some elements in the array may have negative indices, for eg.

| n | x[n] |
| --- | --- |
| -2 | 4 |
| -1 | 5 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |

For the array described above, `x[-2] = 4` and `x[-1] = 5`. This would work kind of like a dictionary. Is there any way to implement this in numpy? I understand that I can just shift everything 2 spots and shift it back when doing the operations, I'm just wondering if there is any other ideal way of dealing with this.

Comment: In `numpy` indices are purely positional.  You may need to maintain a separate indexing array.  That's what `pandas` does.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly for this sort of thing there is pandas. It's build on numpy, is very similar in many regards and should do what you want.

```
import pandas as pd

index = [-2, -1, 0, 1]
data = [4, 5, 3, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x[n]':data},index=index)
```

Gives you

```
    x[n]
-2     4
-1     5
 0     3
 1     1
```

And you can use it similar to numpy e.g.

```
df.loc[-2:-1]
```

gives you

```
    x[n]
-2     4
-1     5
```